# Does Malevolence need an ethereal ghost that is manifested as opposed to a non-ethereal ghost?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Does Malevolence need an ethereal ghost that is manifested as opposed to a non-ethereal ghost? **Is it possible to un-ethereal a ghost?** I thought it's always ethereal, and incorporeal too when manifested only.
Is this a case of bad wording or errata or type-error?

> Once per round, an ethereal ghost can merge its body with a creature on the Material Plane. This ability is similar to a magic jar spell (caster level 10th or the ghost’s Hit Dice, whichever is higher), except that it does not require a receptacle. To use this ability, the ghost must be manifested and it must try move into the target’s space;

This question was in relation to [Can multiple ghosts use Malevolence on one creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76875/can-multiple-ghosts-use-malevolence-on-one-creature?noredirect=1#comment195214_76875)

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, Malevolence requires an ethereal ghost, because it's possible to un-ethereal a ghost

The [ghost](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/ghost.htm) entry says:

> A ghost dwells on the Ethereal Plane and, as an ethereal creature, it cannot affect or be affected by anything in the material world.
>
> ...
>
> A ghost has two home planes, the Material Plane and the Ethereal Plane.

So ghosts are Ethereal simply by virtue of living on the Ethereal Plane. A ghost could *plane shift* or *gate* from the Ethereal to the Material Plane and stop being Ethereal (or for that matter incorporeal, since it can no longer manifest - a ghost may only manifest from the Ethereal Plane, and is not incorporeal unless they manifest).